# Translations of vue-dataset in Vue 3 script setup configuration

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I would like to translate the vue-dataset component but I don't know how to adapt this to a `<script setup>` Composition API format.

The [`vue-dataset` documentation](https://vue-dataset-demo.netlify.app/installation/#translations) says that I can extend the component using its data attribute as follows.

```
import { Dataset } from 'vue-dataset'

export default {
  extends: Dataset,
  data() {
    return {
      // Provide the translated texts here
      datasetI18n: {
        show: 'Show',
        entries: 'entries',
        previous: 'Previous',
        next: 'Next',
        showing: 'Showing',
        showingTo: 'to',
        showingOf: 'of',
        showingEntries: 'entries'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to adapt this to my application using `<script setup>`, also I would like to import the component only when it is going to be used, but still translated.

This is the import that I do in each view where the component is used.

```
import {
    Dataset,
    DatasetItem,
    DatasetInfo,
    DatasetPager,
    DatasetSearch,
    DatasetShow,
} from "vue-dataset";
```

How could I make that every time I `import` it, it is translated?

Answer (score 0):

To adapt the vue-dataset to a  Composition API format in Vue 3 and provide translation, create a wrapper component that provides the translation:

```
<template>
  <Dataset :datasetI18n="datasetI18n" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { Dataset } from 'vue-dataset'

const datasetI18n = ref({
  // Add translations here
});

onMounted(() => {
  import('vue-dataset').then(module => {
    Dataset = module.Dataset;
  });
});
</script>
```

This wrapper uses dynamic import to load vue-dataset only when used. When using this wrapper, the vue-dataset component will load with provided translations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The linter says that $listeners is deprecated and that the assignment of Datase = module.Dataset cannot be done because Dataset is read-only. On the other hand, Dataset does not have the attribute datasetI18n